# react-navigation - Passing params into nested navigator (Getting param in Drawer component but NOT getting it in main routs)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I am navgating to a **StackNavigator (who's default route is a MaterialBottomTabNavigator) wrapped in DrawerNavigator** with a param. I can get the param in Drawer custom component. But can't get the same in StackNavigator's screen. I tried avoiding the BottomTabNav, by changing default route to a plain screen, still the result is same.

Here's my dashboard screen - a tab navigator

```
const Dashboard = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Tab1: Tab1Component,
        Tab2: Tab2Component,
        ...
    }
);
```

This is another screen which I navigate to, from one of the above tabs

```
class Otherscreen extends Component { 
    ...
    render() {
        ...
        <Text>{
            this.props.navigation.getParam('userInfo', 'Not Set')
            /* FAILS!!! */
        }</Text>
        ...
    } 
    ...
}
```

Therefore, this is a stack navigator containing both

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        'Dashboard': {
            'screen': Dashboard,
        },
        'Otherscreen': {
            'screen': Otherscreen
        }
    }
);
```

I need a drawer for the whole thing, so wrapped it all in

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    { //Main screen
        'AppStack': AppStack
    },
    { //Drawer
        'contentComponent': Drawer
    }
);
```

where, the Drawer is

```
class Drawer extends Component { 
    ...
    render() {
        ...
        <Text>{
            this.props.navigation.getParam('userInfo', 'Not Set')
            /* WORKS!!! */
        }</Text>
        ...
    } 
    ...
}
```

For authentication and other things like splash, I am using

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    'Splash': Splash,
    'Auth': AuthStack,
    'App': AppDrawerNavigator,
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Now what I am trying to do is this.

- At 'Splash', I check for last user info.

  - If I get it, I validate the session token to see if it's expired

    - If not expired, **I navigate to 'App' (the AppDrawerNavigator instance above), with the userinfo**
  - If I don't get it, or if session has expired, I navigate to Auth

    - When auth is over, **I navigate to 'App' (the AppDrawerNavigator instance above), with the userinfo**

In either case, *I am going to 'App' with same userinfo param*, **and I COULD get the userinfo param in Drawer component**.

But I am not getting it from any other screen in AppStack. I even tried to avoid the intermediate BottomTabNav by moving up the Otherscreen to first place making it the default, and navigating to 'App" goes to Otherscreen, but the userinfo param is still unavailable.

I suppose I should be able to get the userinfo param from this.props.navigation **on both (A) The drawer component, and (B) AppStack screens**, or at least it's initial screen i.e. the Dashboard component

Here's a minimal demo:
https://github.com/bhave-abhay/PassPropsIntoNestedNav/
Also, this is the bug report
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5646

What's going wrong in this case?!

Comment: Can you add code you are using for navigation?

Comment: @AndroConsis, In Splash's componentDidMount method I am doing

this.props.navigation.navigate('App', {'userInfo': startupCheckResult.userInfo});

Comment: I have created a minimal demo here
https://github.com/bhave-abhay/PassPropsIntoNestedNav/blob/master/App.js#L45

Comment: Did you try this.props.navigation.state.params?

Comment: Yes @SubhenduKundu, and it's reported to be undefined :|
Can you please take a look at the minimal demo I did? I've tried to get the params sent from one route of SwitchNav into DrawerNav's main screen but failed in every way. Ans surprisingly I DO get it in Drawer component itself very well!

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same problem